React JS Horizontal Scroll on wheel for specific div
I want to make my page layout like this
|frame1|
|frame2|
|frame3||frame4||frame5|
|frame6|
I want the page to scroll vertically from frame1 to frame3 and then scroll horizontal to frame5 and then again vertical scroll to frame6
how can I do it using react js vite

You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.
